# Using toFixed(2) in JavaScript is producing undesired results

Tags: javascript, parsefloat, tofixed

I'm doing this:

```
var refundAmount = parseFloat($('#refundAmount2').val().replace('$',''));
var refundReceived = $('#refundReceived');
var remainderAmount = refundAmount-parseFloat(refundReceived.val().replace('$',''));

alert(parseInt(remainderAmount).toFixed(2));
```

No matter what I do, the result always ends with 2 decimal places being '.00'. So if the first number is 200.12 and the second is 100.08, it should be alerting me with 100.04 but instead I get 100.00.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: `parseInt(remainderAmount)` converts the number to an integer and then `toFixed(2)` appends `.00` to it. It might be undesired but it's the predictable result. I think you want `alert(parseFloat(remainderAmount.toFixed(2)));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You used `parseInt` to convert that number to an integer and then used `toFixed(2)` to convert it to a number with 2 decimal places. Adding 2 decimal places to an integer will always result in `.00`.

Try

```
alert(remainderAmount.toFixed(2));
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laucheukhim/hBTnS/1/).

Comment: There is no need for the parseFloat there since remainderAmount is already a number.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting it as an int with parseInt(), then doing the toFixed().  So you're putting decimal places on an int.